# How to focus child item while finger slipping on its parent container like a Linearlayout?

Tags: android, focus, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout which contains some TextView vertically. I have made all TextView focusable.

What I want to do is that when user use finger slip on the LinearLayout from top to Bottom, the focus would change accordingly, the focus should change along with finger movement.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no focus when the user's finger is on screen. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html